# Can't uninstall and reinstall Truffle?

Tags: linux, blockchain, solidity, truffle

Pls help me with command unstall/ install Truffle.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-vbox:~$ sudo npm uninstall -g truffle 
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 
removed 82 packages in 1.793s

ubuntu@ubuntu-vbox:~$ truffle v
Truffle v4.0.4 (core: 4.0.4)
Solidity v0.4.18 (solc-js)

ubuntu@ubuntu-vbox:~$ sudo npm install -g truffle@4.1.15
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
/home/ubuntu/.npm-global/bin/truffle -> /home/ubuntu/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js
+ truffle@4.1.15
added 82 packages in 9.783s

ubuntu@ubuntu-vbox:~$ truffle v
Truffle v4.0.4 (core: 4.0.4)
Solidity v0.4.18 (solc-js)
```

It's still version Truffle v4.0.4 after reinstall version 4.1.15

Answer (score 0):

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/62956

I have used this in the past.

You will need to:

```
which truffle
```

will return:

> /usr/local/bin/truffle

```
rm -f /usr/local/bin/truffle
```

Then proceed with the re-installation procedure.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Sen,
ubuntu@ubuntu-vbox:~$ sudo npm uninstall -g truffle 
removed 27 packages in 1.253s
ubuntu@ubuntu-vbox:~$ sudo npm install -g truffle@4.1.15
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
/home/ubuntu/.npm-global/bin/truffle -> /home/ubuntu/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js
+ truffle@4.1.15
added 82 packages in 9.909s
ubuntu@ubuntu-vbox:~$ truffle v
bash: /usr/bin/truffle: No such file or directory